# Rails 3 upgrade - Routes - Uninitialized Constant expecting different name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, upgrade

I'm upgrading from Rails 2.3.8 to 3.0.3 and am not having fun.  I have a route:

```
# for UserApp objects
  resources :user_apps, :path => "apps" do 
    # A UserApp has_many components
    resources :components, :only => [:index, :update], :controller => "user_app"
    # and a UserApp has_one AppConfig object
    resource :app_config, :only => [:show, :edit, :update], :path => "config/basics", :controller => 'config/basics'
  end
```

The raked routes for this show:

```
edit_user_app_app_config GET    /apps/:user_app_id/config/basics/edit(.:format)         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"config/basics"}
     user_app_app_config GET    /apps/:user_app_id/config/basics(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"config/basics"}
                         PUT    /apps/:user_app_id/config/basics(.:format)           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"config/basics"}
```

but when I link to this path, I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant RbConfig::BasicsController
```

The question is, why did a Rb get prepended here?  (and how do I fix it)

Comment: Man, I'm not sure, but I feel your pain.  I watched Ryan Bates' Railscasts and upgraded like he did without too much pain. (Upgrading to Rails 3 [Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1), [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2), [Part 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the Rb. But I'm sure config is some kind of a reserved word. I had a action method named config in a Rails 2.3.5 app which bombed when upgrading to Rails 3. I had to rename it to make it work. Try renaming the controller and see.